# Socket Programming - Java

Tags: java, sockets, javafx-2

I am sending/receiving objects via socket using `ObjectOnputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` as its client server architecture.

**Scenario:**

It is very basic program where user can have an account where he/she can deposit/withdraw money from his/her account.

User will signup with account number and initial deposit. Below are the screen shots

[image]

*Console output:*

```
Client is connected
Server end
In server for account number 1 we have $123.0 while sending to client

Client end
Response receive from server for account number 1 with balance $123.0
```

User is depositing $2 in his/her account and then fetch updated account. Below are the screen shots

[image]

*Console output:*

```
Server end
In server for account number we have $125.0 while sending to client

Client end
Response receive from server for account number 1 with balance $123.0
```

**Problem:**

As you see above that after user deposit $2 in the account its still $123. Server is sending $125 but client is getting $123. What am I doing wrong? Below is the code

*Client-end code for fetching updated account detail.*

```
public class Home {

    public void initialize(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            Text text = new Text();

            // get balance

            Message message = new Message();

            message.setMessage("getAccount");
            message.setAccount(SimpleClient.account);

            SimpleClient.outToServer.writeObject(message);

            Message reply = (Message) SimpleClient.inFromServer.readObject();

            System.out.println("Client end");

            System.out.println("Response receive from server for account number " + reply.getAccount().getAccountNumber() + " with balance " + reply.getAccount().getBalance() + "\n");  // Here is problem

            text.setText(reply.getMessage());

            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(reply.getIsSuccessful())) {
                SimpleClient.account = reply.getAccount();
                text.setText("Current balance : " + reply.getAccount().getBalance());
            }

            // Below is other stuff

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*Server code to deposit and send updated account to client*

```
public class HandleClient implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream outToClient;
    private ObjectInputStream inFromClient;

    /**
     * The constructor HandleClient() is use to initialize input and output Streams
     * @param socket
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public HandleClient(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Client is connected");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            Message reply = new Message();

            try {
                // Read and write messages from client
                Message message = (Message)inFromClient.readObject();

                String operation = message.getMessage();

                if("signup".equals(operation)) {
                    // Do signup

                } else if("getAccount".equals(operation)) {       // Here is problem
                    // get updated account

                    Account account = message.getAccount();

                    if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(SimpleServer.accounts.containsKey(account.getAccountNumber()))) {
                        reply.setIsSuccessful(Boolean.TRUE);
                        reply.setAccount(SimpleServer.accounts.get(account.getAccountNumber()));

                        System.out.println("Server end");

                        System.out.println("In server for account number " + reply.getAccount().getAccountNumber() + " we have " + reply.getAccount().getBalance() + " while sending to client" + "\n");
                    } else {
                        reply.setIsSuccessful(Boolean.FALSE);
                        reply.setMessage("Account does not exists");
                    }

                } else if("add".equals(operation)) {
                    // deposit amount in user account

                    Account account = message.getAccount();

                    Double amount = (Double) message.getObjects().get(0);

                    if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(SimpleServer.accounts.containsKey(account.getAccountNumber()))) {
                        account = SimpleServer.accounts.get(account.getAccountNumber());

                        account.setBalance(account.getBalance() + amount);

                        SimpleServer.accounts.put(account.getAccountNumber(), account);

                        reply.setIsSuccessful(Boolean.TRUE);
                    } else {
                        reply.setIsSuccessful(Boolean.FALSE);
                        reply.setMessage("Account does not exists");
                    }

                } else if("substract".equals(operation)) {
                    // release amount from user amount

                } else if("transfer".equals(operation)) {
                    // transfer amount from one account to other account

                } else {
                    reply.setIsSuccessful(Boolean.FALSE);
                    reply.setMessage("Unsupported operation");
                }

                outToClient.writeObject(reply);
                outToClient.flush();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HandleClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                // close and return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Client-end) After adding or depositing amount in account I am fetching account again from server (like `new Home().initialize(new Stage())`). I think add is working fine, problem is while getting updated account.

PS: `SimpleServer.accounts` is the `HasMap<String, Account>` i.e. where `key` is `accountNumber`. On demand if you want I can show you my `Account` and `Message` classes, both `implements Serializable`.

**EDIT:**

Blow class view of my project.

[image]

Comment: seem problem is in `readObject` or `writeObject`

Comment: The reply's account field seems remain  not updated.

Comment: Yes, but it was never used before. Like `reply` is new object here.